# XPath retrieve nodeContent

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, xpath, html-parsing

I want to retrieve the name from 'Course Leader' from this webpage http://www.westminster.ac.uk/schools/computing/undergraduate/computer-networks/bsc-honours-computer-network-security . How can this be done? I tried

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]/*[self::h3 or self::h4 and .='Course Leader' or 'Course Leaders']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

but it returns the wrong data .. i need to select the 'nodeContent' after Course Leader.

Comment: How were you able to retrieve the data at all? W3C Validator says this is not valid XML.

Comment: Sorry i pasted wrong snipped, edited op. Also i'm using hpple to parse html data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'content_div')]
    /p[
        (preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h3] or preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h4]) 
            and (preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Course Leader' 
                or preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Course Leaders')
     ]
```